# How to make image 100% height of screensize (responsive) with MDBootstrap

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap

I have a Navbar and image Carousel, I've put the Carousel in a Container and trying to make it so the whole image is displayed responsively under the Navbar on the screen, without having to scroll down. It is almost working, however I have to scroll down a little bit to see the bottom of the image, as you can see here below. Is it because it's not taking into the account the Navbar?

[image]
[image]

```
import React from "react";

import {
  MDBContainer,
  MDBNavbar,
  MDBNavbarBrand,
  MDBNavbarToggler,
  MDBIcon,
  MDBNavbarNav,
  MDBNavbarItem,
  MDBNavbarLink,
  MDBBtn,
  MDBDropdown,
  MDBDropdownToggle,
  MDBDropdownMenu,
  MDBDropdownItem,
  MDBDropdownLink,
  MDBCollapse,
  MDBCarousel,
  MDBCarouselInner,
  MDBCarouselItem,
  MDBCarouselElement,
  MDBCarouselCaption,
} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";

function Home() {
  return <Carousel />;
}

function Carousel() {
  return (
    <MDBContainer style={{height: '100%'}}>
      <MDBCarousel showIndicators showControls fade>
        <MDBCarouselInner>
          <MDBCarouselItem className="active">
            <MDBCarouselElement
              src="/Photos/049A0527.jpg"
              alt="Church Night Landscape"
            />
            <MDBCarouselCaption>
              <h5>First slide label</h5>
              <p>Canon RF 24-105mm f/4L.</p>
              <p>f4.0, Shutter Speed: 1/100, ISO: 100</p>
            </MDBCarouselCaption>
          </MDBCarouselItem>

          <MDBCarouselItem>
            <MDBCarouselElement src="/Photos/049A0547.jpg" alt="Dog Portrait" />
            <MDBCarouselCaption>
              <h5>Second slide label</h5>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </MDBCarouselCaption>
          </MDBCarouselItem>

          <MDBCarouselItem>
            <MDBCarouselElement
              src="/Photos/049A0589.jpg"
              alt="Lake Landscape"
            />
            <MDBCarouselCaption>
              <h5>Third slide label</h5>
              <p>
                Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
              </p>
              s
            </MDBCarouselCaption>
          </MDBCarouselItem>
        </MDBCarouselInner>
      </MDBCarousel>
    </MDBContainer>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's not taking into account the height of the navbar. You could set the navbar height to something like 15vh and the carousel to 85vh, so that they total to 100

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just tried changing the Navbar height, which messes up the fluid properties, it looks ok until screen size changes